# How to make the chat search box in Gmail show mobile number or other details when viewing contacts profile?

Tags: gmail, search, contacts

To make phone calls (not using Google Voice/Softphone but normal phones) or see some other details like Company etc. of a person whose details are added in my Google Contacts, I generally use the chat search box on the left side to quickly lookup a contact's detail.

Hovering on any search result, apart from other options like Mail, "view recent conversations etc", the search result of the search box also has "X's Profile":

[image: Screenshot]

I want to know how to add more fields like mobile number etc. to this "display Profile" popup (currently it only shows email and photo).

If there is any separate Gmail gadget or a way to do this kind of quick lookup, that should also be fine.

```
Operating system: WinXP
Firefox 3.6.1.7
Your antivirus software: McAfee
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that under *gmail's contact quick search* but you can [sync your contacts](http://www.google.com/sync/pc.html) and use your preferred application (or even [Outlook](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync)) to search them. As a bonus, you get synced calendar.

Another option within gmail is enabling [keyboard shortcuts](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=6594), typing <kbd>g</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> then <kbd>/</kbd> to search, and <kbd>g</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to go back to inbox. At least to me that's quick enough.